# TYPO3 Multilingual (RTL Stylesheet) Support

Tags: php, content-management-system, typo3, typoscript

I'm trying to add Arabic "RTL" language support for my site which implemented using TYPO3 CMS the problem is that the available references shows how to support multi language with the same CSS but what I want to know is how to put two different CSS "RTL" and "LTR" one for English and the other for Arabic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you decide, whether RTL or LTR styles have to be applied? Based on the language? I just know that there is a config.htmlTag_dir property, which enables you to set the *dir* attribute of the <html> tag.

You should be able to use a TypoScript condition executing a user function (userFunc, [see TSref](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.5.1/view/1/4/)), inside which you add the specific style sheets using page.includeCSS.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I'll checkout this link and I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

```
# English Lan ID 0

   config.language = en
   config.htmlTag_langKey = en
   config.sys_language_uid = 0
   config.htmlTag_dir = ltr

   page.includeCSS {
         css1 = path-to-css/en.css

   }

# Arabic Lan ID 1

[globalVar = GP:L = 1]

config.language = ar
config.htmlTag_langKey = ar
config.sys_language_uid = 1
config.htmlTag_dir = rtl

    page.includeCSS {
      css1 = path-to-css/ar.css

    }

[global]
```

Thank you
Freearabicwebsite

Answer (score 1):

I would add a custom field to sys_language for RTL of type checkbox and adding the RTL stylesheet with stdWrap.if accessing the cur language record.